# How to calculate the integral $\int \frac{\exp(i \vec{q} \cdot \vec{r})}{|\vec{r}|}\mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}$.

Tags: calculus

How to calculate the integral
$\int \frac{\exp(i\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r})}{|\vec{r}|}\mathrm{d}^3\vec{r}$.

I try to calculate it in the polar coordinates. I first translate it into $$ \iiint e^ {iqr \cos\theta} r \sin\theta \,\mathrm{d}r\, \mathrm{d}\phi\, \mathrm{d}\theta$$ and then calculate it by part. But I get the $\frac{4\pi}{q^2}\cos{|q||r|}$, but the right result is $\frac{4\pi}{q^2}$.

Comment: What's the integration domain? All of $\mathbb{R}^3$? If so, the integrand does not decay fast enough at infinity for this integral to be finite: If you perform the $\theta$-integral from $0$ to $\pi$ and the $\phi$-integral from $0$ to $2\pi$, you are left with $\frac{4\pi}{q^2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(qr)\, \mathrm{d} r$ which does not converge.

Comment: Your attempt keeps an $r$-dependence, which implies you didn't do a triple integral over $\Bbb R^3$. As @SvenPistre notes, that integral diverges. If this were Physics SE, we'd [give the integrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization#Heat_kernel_regularization) an extra $e^{-mr}$ factor with $m>0$, then compute the $m\to0^+$ one-sided limit, which gives you what you want.

Comment: See [this Terry Tao blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/), around equation (8).